# Why i am getting Linking error on compilation even i have set all the Path for Library

Tags: c, visual-studio, nmake, makefile

There are I am getting compilation error using nmake.

There i have 2 files TEST.C and TEST.DEF in one directory and one make file name as "Makefile" and other make file name as "Makefile.pc". This "Makefile.pc" have code as given below in one line

include Makefile

means only including the Makefile in Makefile.pc file.

and Makefile contains the code to build the my code i will paste down the Makefile code

```
# Targets and objects =========================================================
WIN_TARGET    = test.exe
WIN_SRCS      = TEST.C
WIN_OBJS      = $(WIN_SRCS:.C=.OBJ)
WIN_DEF       = TEST.DEF

# Compiler stuff ==============================================================
CMP_EXEC      = CL /Fo
CMP_FLAGS_WIN = /c /nologo

# Linker stuff ================================================================
LNK_EXEC      = LINK
LNK_FLAGS_WIN = /NOLOGO /ONERROR:NOEXE /NOD /ALIGN:16 /STACK:10240

# Rules =======================================================================

all: $(WIN_TARGET)

build: regenerate all

$(WIN_TARGET): $(WIN_OBJS)
    @ ECHO ~~~~~ Linking $(WIN_TARGET)
    @ $(LNK_EXEC) $(LNK_FLAGS_WIN) $(WIN_OBJS),$(WIN_TARGET),NUL,llibcew \
      libw,$(WIN_DEF)
    @ ECHO ~~~~~ $(WIN_TARGET) done


$(WIN_OBJS): $(WIN_SRCS) Makefile
    @ ECHO ===== Compiling $(*).C
    @ $(CMP_EXEC)$(@) $(CMP_FLAGS_WIN) $(@D)\$(*F).C

regenerate:

clean:
    @ DEL $(WIN_TARGET) $(WIN_OBJS)
```

there are two libraries "llibcew" and "libw"

The Linker-Error I am getting as:

```
"LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "CCM_NPW.OBJ,ccm_npw.exe,NUL,llibcew".
```

Comment: You should not have comma between the linker files. As you could see in the error message it treats `CCM_NPW.OBJ,ccm_npw.exe,NUL,llibcew` as a *single file name*.

Comment: There's other problems as well, like you listing the target (output) file as an input file. I suggest you take some time to [read the `link` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linking?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I don't know nmake but if it's like make, then the rule `$(WIN_OBJS): $(WIN_SRCS)` will be wrong as soon as `WIN_SRCS` contains more than one file: it will always recompile the first file in the list.

Comment: @MadScientist In that aspect, both `nmake` and `make` are similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you for such a use full solution for my query, now the issue fixed there were i make separated lib directory path in environment variable and its working fine.